# Junit Test for testing data in NamingEnumeration in LDAP connectivity test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have written the below code for getting results from LDAP.
From the results I needed to extract a single entry and perform operations on it.
This code is running fine.
But the problem is when I am trying to write Unit test for it.
I needed to load test data or mock something somehow to write tests for the piece of code.
Can someone help me guide in the write direction.

Code in discussion as below :

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = dirContext.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

if (results.hasMoreElements()) {

    List<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
    SearchResult searchResult = results.nextElement();
    NamingEnumeration ldapAttributes = searchResult.getAttributes().getAll();

    while (ldapAttributes.hasMore()) {
        Attribute attr = (Attribute) (ldapAttributes.next());
        for (int i = 0; i < attr.size(); i++) {
            if (attr.get(i).toString().startsWith("CN=GG-PaaS-logging-service")) {
                String commonName = attr.get(i).toString();
                int startIndex = commonName.indexOf("=") + 1;
                int endIndex = commonName.indexOf(",");
                commonName = commonName.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                securityGroups.add(commonName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see (at least) 7 dependencies need to be mocked in your code.

The reason why we have to mock that much is because your code fails to follow the *Law of Demeter* aka *Don't talk to strangers*. You could avoid half of the mocking if the input to your method would be `ldapAttributes` directly.

I guess in your real code you're actually doing something with `securityGroups`. In your example in is getting garbage collected when leaving the `if`...

So here is how I would write a test:

```
class LdapLoggingServiceExctractorTest{
 @Rule 
 public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJunit.rule()
 @Mock 
 private DirContext dirContext;
 @Mock 
 NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results;
 @Mock 
 private SearchResult loggerSearchResult;
 @Mock 
 private Attributes ldapAttributes; // same name but different object!!
 @Mock 
 private NamingEnumeration ldapAttributeEnum;
 @Mock 
 private Attribute attr;

 @Before
 public void setup(){
  doReturn(results).when(dirContext).search(any(Name.class),anyString(),any(SearchControls));
  doReturn(loggerSearchResult).when(results).nextElement();
  doReturn(ldapAttributes).when(loggerSearchResult).getAttributes();
  doReturn(ldapAttributeEnum).when(loggerSearchResult).getAll();
  doReturn(true).when(ldapAttributeEnum).hasMore();
  doReturn(attr).when(ldapAttributeEnum).next();
  doReturn(1).when(attr).size();
  doReturn(THE_VALID_LOGGER_ENTRY_STRING).when(attr).get(0);
 }


 @Test
 public void extractLogger_singleResultSingleAttribut_addsLoggersCommonNameToList(){
   LdapLoggingServiceExctractor ldapLoggingServiceExctractor = new LdapLoggingServiceExctractor();

   ldapLoggingServiceExctractor.extractLogger(dirContext);

   assertThat(ldapLoggingServiceExctractor.getSecurityGroups().get(0),equalTo(LOGGER_COMMON_NAME));
  }
}
```

---

> Can you explain "You could avoid half of the mocking if the input to your method would be ldapAttributes directly." I didn't quite understand it. – Nirmalya Guha Khasnobis

your code snipped starts with:

> ```
> if (results.hasMoreElements()) {
>    List<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
>    SearchResult searchResult = results.nextElement();
>    NamingEnumeration ldapAttributes = searchResult.getAttributes().getAll();
> ```

This is "boilerplate" code needed because of the way the LDAP framework stores the information. In my understanding of the *separation of concerns* principle this extraction of the `ldapAttributes` is the responsibility of a different unit. So my approach I would have a separate class `LdapLoggingServiceExctractor` with a method like this:

```
public void addLoggerToSecurityGroup(NamingEnumeration ldapAttributes,List<String> securityGroups){
    while (ldapAttributes.hasMore()) {
        Attribute attr = (Attribute) (ldapAttributes.next());
        for (int i = 0; i < attr.size(); i++) {
            if (attr.get(i).toString().startsWith("CN=GG-PaaS-logging-service")) {
                String commonName = attr.get(i).toString();
                int startIndex = commonName.indexOf("=") + 1;
                int endIndex = commonName.indexOf(",");
                commonName = commonName.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                securityGroups.add(commonName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the test would simplify to this:

```
class LdapLoggingServiceExctractorTest{
 @Rule 
 public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJunit.rule();
 @Mock 
 private NamingEnumeration ldapAttributeEnum;
 @Mock 
 private Attribute attr;
 @Before
 public void setup(){
  doReturn(true,false).when(ldapAttributeEnum).hasMore(); // corrected to avoid endless loop...
  doReturn(attr).when(ldapAttributeEnum).next();
  doReturn(1).when(attr).size();
  doReturn(THE_VALID_LOGGER_ENTRY_STRING).when(attr).get(0);
 }
 @Test
 public void extractLogger_singleResultSingleAttribut_addsLoggersCommonNameToList(){
   List<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
   LdapLoggingServiceExctractor ldapLoggingServiceExctractor = new LdapLoggingServiceExctractor();

   ldapLoggingServiceExctractor.addLoggerToSecurityGroup(ldapAttributeEnum, securityGroups);

   assertThat(securityGroups.get(0),equalTo(LOGGER_COMMON_NAME));
  }
}
```

From the 7 dependencies to be mocked in the original version only 2 are  left.

Off cause this does not mean that (most of) the other mocks are not needed.
They will be moved to an independent test with the new class which the "boilerplate" code will be moved to.

Comment: Thank you Timothy for the unit test.
Again that is right that I am performing some more operation on the `securityGroups` so it won't be garbage collected.
I think you also meant that this code can be simplified to bring down the number of mocks. Tha above code is just the snippet.
Can you explain "You could avoid half of the mocking if the input to your method would be ldapAttributes directly." I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Well, in that case I would stick to my code as I am actually testing the class and method which has the "boilerplate" code. :)
The method is currently being called from another class and I am just returning the securityGroups for more operation in the calling class.

Comment: Being a newbie to Mocking, it was confusing to understand until I saw this answer.  So elegant and simply explained. My +1.